# Having two keys for each value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `City` class

```
class City(object):

  def __init__(self, name):
     self.name = name
```

Then I put it into a dictionary:

```
c = City('NYC')
cities = dict()
cities[c] = 1
```

I can access NYC's value with `cities[c]`.  Could I do the same with `cities['NYC']`?  Basically, I want the `City` instance and `City.name` instance variable to refer to the same key.

I thought of having a separate dictionary `names = {'NYC': c}`, so I could do `cities[names['NYC']]`.  Are there better ways?  Ideally I won't need to use seperate variables and would only have to modify the internals of either `City` class or `cities` dictionary.

Comment: What you don't use `cities[c.name]`?

Comment: @Kasramvd I will put more instance variables inside class `City`, so I want to store the object itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement is `__hash__` method where you has the name attribute and an `__eq__` that compares for equality based on  the name attribute:

```
class City(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
```

Output:

```
In [8]: c = City('NYC')

In [9]: cities = dict()

In [10]: cities[c] = 1

In [11]: cities[c]
Out[11]: 1

In [12]: cities[c.name]
Out[12]: 1
```

The instances hash value is based on its name attribute so a lookup using the object or the attribute with instance.name will hash to the same value.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried overriding `__hash__` but forgot to do the same for `__eq__`, forgot I needed both.